# Caml for "multi lookup has no values" condition

Tags: caml, multiple-values, multi-select

I need to get items from my list where multiLookup field contains value (for example, value is 42) or has no values.
First part is simple:

```
<Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='mlookup' LookupId='true' />
    <Value Type='Integer'>42</Value>
</Eq>
```

Problems in second part.
I tried to use `<IsNull><FieldRef Name='mlookup' /></IsNull>` but it falls with ArgumentException ("Value does not fall within the expected range.")
Is there any solutions for my problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you ran `<IsNull><FieldRef Name='mlookup' /></IsNull>` did you remove the `<Eq>` ? This should work: `<Query><Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name="Customer" /></IsNull></Where></Query>`

Comment: What's the exact query you're using to combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Query is right.. problem is something else.. I tried it in my environment it is working fine.. try it by using **CAML Builder**.. it will show you result of you query also..

```
<Where>
      <IsNull>
         <FieldRef Name='DestinationColumn' />
      </IsNull>
   </Where>
```

Comment: Oh, you are right. The problem is in another part of query. Thanks for helping to see it

Comment: Dont forget to Mark as Answer..